# How long to cook 500g of boneless pork leg?

Tags: food-safety, meat, cooking-time

I cut a 1.8kg boneless pork leg into three pieces and now am unsure how long is enough to cook it. How long will a 500g piece take to cook?

Comment: How do you intend to cook it, and what is the final result you want to achieve?

Comment: Just nice not to dry and I have taken the cracking of the top to do separately just want to make sure my pork is cooked

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you invest in a meat thermometer. A quality one such as a [thermapen](https://www.thermoworks.com/). [Probe thermometers](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-probe-thermometer/) (link to review site) are a very useful tool as well.

Roasting meat is not a as much a question of time, but of temperature. You are tying to cook pork to a **temperature** you desire: maybe 60 C (140 F) or 70 C (160 F) depending on your desired taste and recipe. How much time that will take is a function of a number of factors, including the cooking method, oven temperature (if you are roasting), and the size and weight of the pieces being cooked (something you did specify). Having a thermometer to measure the internal temperature will tell you much more about when the meat is done than how much time you are cooking it.